# How do you prompt a user to choose a series of points from an external application in Revit 2014?

Tags: c#, vb.net, revit

Stack,

I'm developing an application to work with Revit 2014.  Whether it will run inside of Revit or outside as an external application is yet to be determined.  At this point, I'm attempting to prove the concept using commands through the add in tab.  The goal is to allow the user to create conduit in Revit through an external interface, but I can't seem to find a method similar to AutoCAD's 'Pick Point'.  I'd like for the user to select a point, or series of, and have the XYZ(s) communicated back to me via the API.  I'll use those points to perform some calculations, adding/filling shared parameters based on the work being done, then draw the conduit for them, just as Revit would.  I know that Revit is lacking in their Electrical API, so if it has to be done with a pipe or placeholder and then converted to a conduit, that's fine too.

I've successfully created conduith/pipe/pipe placeholders with known XYZ's (Hardcoded) but the idea is have the user choose the XYZ.  Am I way off base with this?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The development is being done with the Revit 2014 API, Visual Studio 2010 (Express for now, with intentions to jump to Ultimate when funding comes through) and believe it or not VB6.

Thanks in advance,
Runnin

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using the Selection.PickPoint() Method? Something like:
XYZ pickedPoint = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Selection.PickPoint();

Comment: That was what I was looking for and more.  It brought to my attention the other Pick methods as well (e.g. Object, etc).